# How to assign the output of a command to a variable?

Tags: bash, variables, operators, variable-assignment

this is probably a very stupid question; in a bash script, given the output of, for instance;

```
awk '{print $7}' temp
```

it gives 0.54546

I would like to give this to a variable, so I tried:

```
read ENE <<< $(awk '{print $7}' temp)
```

but I get

```
Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Could you tell me why, and what is the easiest way to do this assignment?

Thanks

Comment: Although awkward, `read ENE <<< $(awk '{print $7}' temp)` works for me, so I am unable to say what is broken there? Are you sure you are working with bash and not some other shell? What `bash --version` are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your syntax should be

```
read ENE <<<$(awk '{print $1}' file)
```

you can directly assign the value as well

```
ENE=$(awk '{print $7}' temp)
```

you can also use the shell

```
$ var=$(< temp)
$ set -- $var
$ echo $7
```

or you can read it into array

```
$ declare -a array
$ read -a array <<<$(<file)
$ echo ${array[6]}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do command substitution as:

```
ENE=$(awk '{print $7}' temp)
```

or

```
ENE=`awk '{print $7}' temp`
```

This will assign the value `0.54546` to the variable `ENE`

Comment: great, thanks a lot!  By the way, anybody knows why the previous one did not wok?

Answer (score 0):

In general, Bash is kinda sensitive to spaces (requiring them some places, and breaking if they are added to other places,) which in my opinion is too bad. Just remember that there should be no space on either side of an equal sign, there should be no space *after* a dollar sign, and parentheses should be lined with spaces ( like this ) (not like this.)

`command` and $( command ) are the same thing, but $( this version can be $( nested ) ) whereas "this version can be `embedded in strings.` "